# How can I orderBy data based on user's data use Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables, `jobs` and `users`

jobs table

| name | grade_id | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Data 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Data 3 | 2 | 2 |
| Data 4 | 1 | 2 |

users table

| name | grade_id | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 1 |
| Doe | 2 | 2 |

How can I order job's data by the most relevant data based on users data using Eloquent?

what i want is when user `Doe`  access job page it will return based on `Doe's` city_id then `Doe's` grade_id, example :

returned job's data

| name | grade_id | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data 3 | 2 | 2 |
| Data 4 | 1 | 2 |
| Data 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Data 1 | 1 | 1 |

Anyone can help or give me keyword to googling it?
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: you need to join the table and perform the order by on it, also don't forget to use where condition to filter the user table.

Answer (score 1):

When `Doe` hits the `GET /jobs` route,  you can use the `auth()` [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-auth) to access his info and [orderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#orderby) like this:

```
$user = auth()->user(); 
$job = Job::orderBy('grade_id', $user->grade_id)->orderBy('city_id', $user->city_id)->get();
```